# DIV positioning using CSS issue

Tags: css

is there any way to force div to appear on page side by side not one after one.

suppose i have main div like and it has many child div.

```
<div id='main'>
<div>my content 1 </div>
<div>my content 2 </div>
<div>my content 3 </div>

<div>my content 4 </div>
<div>my content 5 </div>
<div>my content 6 </div>

<div>my content 7 </div>
<div>my content 8 </div>
<div>my content 9 </div>
</div>
```

now i want that on each line three div will come side by side and there will be some padding....so if three div appear on each line then three line will be required to show all div content. i know css float property can be use to accquire the effect but i am not good in css. so some one help please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the float method, or you could use `display: inline-block`, as per [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVXwe/1/):

```
div#main {
    width: 500px;
}

div#main div {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;

    /* IE hacks */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

`div#main` doesn't have to have a width. It's given one here just as a demonstration.

Answer (score 4):

```
#main div{float:left; width:33%; display:block;}
```

This should align them next to each other

Comment: but i want three div appear on each line not all...how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

give 1 2 & 3 the attribute `float: left;`

give 4 the attribute `clear: both;`

give 4 5 & 6 the attribute `float: left;`

give 7 the attribute `clear: both;`

give 7, 8, 9 the attribute `float: left;`

and please dont use the attribute "padding"! Its displayed differently in each browser!

Use a surrounding div with a margin instead!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same distance between every element the easiest way is to float the children, set a  negative margin on the parent element that has the same size as the margin on the children, and make the parent x times as wide as the children + x times the margin (where x is 3 if you want 3 elements next to each other) like this:

```
#main { margin: -10px 0 0 -10px; width: 330px}
#main > div { margin: 10px 0 0 10px; width: 100px; float: left;}
```

Don't forget to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent if you don't want it to collapse.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mCEGf/